# Google Trends for Website suddenly closed?

Tags: google

Has google closed it's Trends for Website service?

http://trends.google.com/websites?q=wikipedia.org

I can't find any news on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/09/more-spring-cleaning.html

> We've merged Insights for Search into a revamped Google Trends. You
>   can now see search trends and compare search volume patterns across
>   specific regions, categories, time frames and properties in a single
>   place: google.com/trends. **We will no longer support Trends for
>   Websites**, which allowed people to compare traffic to and audiences of
>   different websites.

Comment: So sad... Any alternative to know something more about a website?

Comment: There's no credible information available for websites such as search volume traffic etc. Think about it. Only the website owners have access to their raw log files. Only they have access to Google Analytics. Don't trust what any website tells you about another it's just a guess and bad ones at that. If you need to know about a website run a few keyword searches in Google see where they show up. If they're on the first page they are doing well. Above the fold even better. If you aren't ranking near them, they're doing better in the organics.